# MediaDrm provideKeyResponse interrupts audio streaming in ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, drm, exoplayer2.x, widevine

I'm using ExoPlayer to play audio Dash content licensed with Widevine. In most devices it works fine, but in certain Huawei and Xiaomi devices the audio gets interrupted for a few milliseconds when native MediaDrm.provideKeyResponse(byte[] scope, byte[] response) is called. How can I prevent this from happening?

I'm using ExoPlayer 2.9.1, but even if I upgrade to the latest version this problem still persists.